# Encapsulate dependency/coupling and hierachy of static data list

Tags: c#, static, decoupling

Apologies for the title, I really don't know what to call this problem. I have an abstract class which describes the interface of some data collection. I would like to retrieve an instance list of all classes that derives from this, without littering the base class or the code that uses it with references to the new type name. In effect, I want to be able to add new derived classes of the base and the rest of the code should work unaffected.

Maybe some code will help illustrate the problem:

```
public abstract class BaseData
{
    public static List<BaseData> getCollection()
    {
        return collection;
    }

    static private List<BaseData> collection = new List<BaseData>();

    // the actual part of the interface.
    public abstract int[] getSomeData();

    protected BaseData()
    {
        // when some derived class is statically created, they get added to the static list.
        collection.Add(this);
    }
}
```

And then I can use the interface like this:

```
// some actual code file:
class App
{
    public App()
    {
        foreach(var dataimpl in BaseData.getCollection())
        {
            //.. do something here.
            var data = dataimpl.getSomeData();
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is, that I can now add new cases to this data collection in another file, without altering the other two pieces of code, like so:

```
// hidden implementation classes
class SomeImplementation1 : BaseData
{
    // register the class in the base class list
    static private SomeImplementation1 register = new SomeImplementation1();
    public override int[] getSomeData() { return null; }
    private SomeImplementation1() { }
}

class SomeImplementation2 : BaseData
{
    // register the class in the base class list
    static private SomeImplementation2 register = new SomeImplementation2();
    public override int[] getSomeData() { return null; }
    private SomeImplementation2() { }
}
```

The use cases are many, tests, data and such. **The problem, however,** is, that the static register variable in the child classes isn't actually instantiated (and thus, the parent constructor is not run, which in turn means the class is not registered in the collection) before the child class is referenced - that is, the static initializers will not run before an instance is created.

This then requires me to reference the child classes somewhere in a list, which defeats the whole purpose of this system. **My question is**, is this a common pattern - is there an existing solution or a somehow similar implementation to this - or can this code be fixed somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the "abstract class which describes the interface" and use an actual interface.

```
interface IHaveData
{
    int[] getSomeData();
}
```

Now this frees you up to implement registrations however you want. Here's one simple way that fits with your initial code:

```
class BaseData
{
    private static readonly List<IHaveData> collection = new List<IHaveData>();

    public static IEnumerable<IHaveData> getCollection()
    {
        return collection;
    }

    public static void Register(IHaveData instance)
    {
        collection.Add(instance);
    }
}

class SomeImplementation1 : IHaveData
{
    private static readonly SomeImplementation1 registration = new SomeImplementation1();

    private SomeImplementation1()
    {
        BaseData.Register(this);
    }

    public int[] getSomeData() { return null; }
}

class SomeImplementation2 : IHaveData
{
    private static readonly SomeImplementation2 registration = new SomeImplementation2();

    private SomeImplementation2()
    {
        BaseData.Register(this);
    }

    public int[] getSomeData() { return null; }
}
```

**UPDATE**
You will need a container of some kind and manually register your instances or use reflection to instantiate your instances and add them to the container.

```
class SomeImplementation1 : IHaveData
{
    public int[] getSomeData() { return null; }
}

class SomeImplementation2 : IHaveData
{
    public int[] getSomeData() { return null; }
}
```

Manual Registration (Safest, but you do have to edit the registrations for each new implementation)

```
class BaseData
{
    private static readonly List<IHaveData> collection = new List<IHaveData>
    {
        new SomeImplementation1(),
        new SomeImplementation2()
        //as you add more implementations, you'll need to add them here
    };

    public static IEnumerable<IHaveData> getCollection()
    {
        return collection;
    }
}
```

Automatic Registration (No more editing registrations, but any constructor changes and you get runtime errors and tricky to debug)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class BaseData
{
    private static List<IHaveData> collection;

    public static IEnumerable<IHaveData> getCollection()
    {
        if (collection == null)
        {
            var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(type =>
                    type.IsClass &&
                    !type.IsAbstract && 
                    type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IHaveData)));

            //All implementation must have the same constructor signature. In this case, a parameterless constructor.
            collection = new List<IHaveData>(types.Select(x => (IHaveData)Activator.CreateInstance(x)));
        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's definitely another nice take on the implementation, but it still suffers from the same problem: If you call getCollection(), the collection is empty because the child implementation's static initializers haven't run yet.

Comment: Sorry, I should've tested the code. Make the registrations public and they should be there. A private static that is never used won't be initialized. In fact, I bet the compiler removes that line all together since it's never used.

Comment: I've added updates to the code. Tested both manual registration and reflection registration and both work fine.